# Unable to make API calls using react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a VM running locally that's built using Vagrant. I am able to curl and go to the URL directly from the browser. For some reason, when I make the same call in my react-native app using the `fetch` API, it keeps giving me the `Network request failed` error.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
fetchData() {

  this.setState({ isLoading: true });

  var baseURL = 'https://192.168.33.33/api/session';

  console.log('URL: >>> ' + baseURL);

  fetch(baseURL)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseData) => {
    console.log(responseData);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  })
  .done();
}
```

The `baseURL` log there returns the right URL and the error looks like so:

```
URL: >>> http://192.168.33.33/api/session
TypeError: Network request failed {stack: (...), message: "Network request failed"}
  message: "Network request failed"
  stack: (...)
  get stack: function () { [native code] }
  set stack: function () { [native code] }
  __proto__: Error
```

I thought it might've been an issue with my VM not being accessible somehow by my app, so I went ahead and deployed it to a real server and it still gave the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: does `https://192.168.33.33/api/session` maybe require some kind of headers on your get request?

Comment: @lyjackal I don't think so, all the code does is this: http://d.pr/n/18BiU/3kXPWHcD

Comment: If you use the XMLHttpRequest object instead of fetch, do you get the same error? Is CORS setup correctly?

Comment: Can you provide us with the URL of your real server so that we can possibly reproduce the error?

Comment: Did you check the same origin policy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the problem and solved it.

The issue was caused by having self-signed certificate in the API server without a self created CA.

I could try creating my own CA and then create a certificate from that but I went ahead and got a cheap real SSL cert. That solved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I think you might be facing the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) constraint.

There are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) ways of workaround it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! unfortunately, that wasn't the case.

Comment: This doesn't apply to react native apps.

Comment: same origin policy is only for the browser!