# React-native fetch() from https server with self-signed certificate

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to communicate with https server having self-signed certificate.

I can do this from .NET application (using ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback event), from native iOs application (using allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost) or from web browser (just need to declare that the certificate is trusted).

But I can't get it to work in react-native application (neither in Android nor in iOS simulator).

I have tried different things but still not succeed.

I know there are some similar topics there:
[Ignore errors for self-signed SSL certs using the fetch API in a ReactNative App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32892161/ignore-errors-for-self-signed-ssl-certs-using-the-fetch-api-in-a-reactnative-app)
[React Native XMLHttpRequest request fails if ssl (https) certificate is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31249559/react-native-xmlhttprequest-request-fails-if-ssl-https-certificate-is-not-vali)
[Fetch in react native wont work with ssl on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655832/fetch-in-react-native-wont-work-with-ssl-on-android)
[Problems fetching data from a SSL based Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34256675/problems-fetching-data-from-a-ssl-based-server)
[Unable to make API calls using react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450414/unable-to-make-api-calls-using-react-native)

But they either do not contain answers or do not working (and they do not cover android programming at all). Searching other resources was not productive as well.

I believe there should be an easy way to work with self-signed certificate. Am I wrong? Does anybody know it (both for iOS and Android)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore errors for self-signed SSL certs using the fetch API in a ReactNative App?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32892161/ignore-errors-for-self-signed-ssl-certs-using-the-fetch-api-in-a-reactnative-app)

Comment: Thank you for a pointing. The solution is not for self-sighed certificate literally, but we will try it.

Comment: Right - I don't think self-signed certificates are the helpful approach, so in that regard, your question is somewhat an X/Y problem. http://xyproblem.info/ I'm not sure there is any way to get self-signed certificates to work with React Native. I think you would need to write some Objective-C to allow it, and that is just putting a nasty bandaid on the problem rather than really solving it.

Comment: If you're using Expo, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70775576/4350421. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Disclaimer: This solution should be temporary and documented so that it won't stay in the production phase of the software, this is for development only.

For iOS, all you have to do is, open your xcodeproject (inside your iOS folder in RN) once you have that open, go to RCTNetwork.xcodeproj and in that project, navigate to RCTHTTPRequestHandler.m

In that file you will see a line like this:

```m
#pragma mark - NSURLSession delegate
```

right after that line, add this function

```m
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition, NSURLCredential *credential))completionHandler
{
  completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust]);
}
```

And voila, you can now make insecure calls to your API without a valid certificate.

That should be enough, but if you are still having problems, you might need to go to your project's info.plist, left click on it and choose open as... source code.

and at the end just add

```xml
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>subdomain.example.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

so your file will look like this

```xml
    ...
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
  <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>subdomain.example.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

For a real production ready solution, https://stackoverflow.com/a/36368360/5943130 that solution is better

Comment: I'll add the answer for Android in a week or so, if you need it now, let me know and maybe I can show you what I've done in Android so far

Comment: It did it in iOS! Looking forward to solution for android.

Comment: Could you please help me out how to do this for android? Best regards

Comment: I'm sorry it has taken me so long to give the Android answer, it's just that I haven't fiddled with it in over a month... I do have an idea on how to do it, It's just a painstakingly cumbersome process, Basically, you need to build RN from source https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/android-building-from-source.html 
in that source you need to find if they are using HttpsURLConnection or HttpClient. After that, I could tell you what code to insert to trust all certificates

Comment: @SantiagoJimenezWilson: Do you have Android answer in 2017? Thanks.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! (If only I can upvote a million times, that's how much you saved me lol).

Comment: Can we avoid this duck taping by buying SSL cert (RapidSSL etc)?

Comment: @svlada Yes, you should definitely buy the SSL cert. This kind of hackityhack should never ever be used in production

Comment: it's works for IOS! thanks.
But, do you have android answer?

Comment: @NamVu check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56715393/6009502 for android

Comment: For me the file is `RCTHTTPRequestHandler.mm`

Comment: Is this working after upgrading to ios v17.4? I was using this workaround till the last version of ios. But suddenly after upgrade, it stopped working.

Answer (score 29):

I am also faced the same issue in android. I copied the code from the answer at [Trusting all certificates with okHttp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509296/trusting-all-certificates-with-okhttp/25992879#25992879) to create a solution:

> ```java
> import com.facebook.react.modules.network.OkHttpClientFactory;
> import com.facebook.react.modules.network.OkHttpClientFactory;
> import com.facebook.react.modules.network.OkHttpClientProvider;
> import com.facebook.react.modules.network.ReactCookieJarContainer;
>
> import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
> import java.util.ArrayList;
>
> import java.util.List;
>
> import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
>
>
> import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
> import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
> import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
> import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
> import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
> import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
>
> import okhttp3.CipherSuite;
> import okhttp3.ConnectionSpec;
> import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
> import okhttp3.TlsVersion;
>
> import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;
>
> public class CustomClientFactory implements OkHttpClientFactory {
>     private static final String TAG = "OkHttpClientFactory";
>     @Override
>     public OkHttpClient createNewNetworkModuleClient() {
>         try {
>             // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
>             final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
>                     new X509TrustManager() {
>                         @Override
>                         public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
>                         }
>
>                         @Override
>                         public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
>                         }
>
>                         @Override
>                         public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
>                             return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
>                         }
>                     }
>             };
>
>             // Install the all-trusting trust manager
>             final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
>             sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
>             // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
>             final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
>
>
>
>             OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
>                     .connectTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).readTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
>                     .writeTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).cookieJar(new ReactCookieJarContainer());
>             builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager) trustAllCerts[0]);
>             builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
>                 @Override
>                 public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
>                     return true;
>                 }
>             });
>
>             OkHttpClient okHttpClient = builder.build();
>             return okHttpClient;
>         } catch (Exception e) {
>             Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
>             throw new RuntimeException(e);
>         }
>     }
>
> }
> ```

And inside our Android application MainApplication.java:

> ```java
> @Override
>  public void onCreate() {
>    super.onCreate();
>    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);  
>    OkHttpClientProvider.setOkHttpClientFactory(new CustomClientFactory()); //add this line.
> }
> ```

Comment: Can you explain this? You're creating a new file with what name? Any imports inside the MainApplication.java?

Comment: i got stuck with this error cannot find symbol
    OkHttpClientProvider.setOkHttpClientFactory(new CustomClientFactory());

Comment: I made it work by adding the package name at the very top of the CustomClientFactory file
`package com.your_package_name_here;`

Comment: also add in MainApplication "import com.facebook.react.modules.network.OkHttpClientProvider;"

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you very much (y)

Comment: this worked for me

Answer (score 8):

I got this working on Android by doing the following:

1. Install the CA on your device under Settings -> Security & location > Advanced > Encryption & credentials > Install from storage. You can confirm it's installed correctly by visiting the domain through a web browser on your device. If the certificate validates, then the CA is installed.
2. Create a network security configuration at `res/xml/network_security_config.xml` with the following contents. Update the domain(s).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <!-- For React Native Hot-reloading system -->
        <!-- If you are running on a device insert your computer IP -->
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">your self signed domain</domain>

        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>

    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false" />
</network-security-config>
```

3. Reference this configuration file from your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... >
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
                    ... >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: it randomly started working after a few days that i implemented this! now it switches on/off promptly if i remove it from the `AndroidManifest.xml`. go figure :P

Answer (score 6):

This is happened due to self signed certificate used for encryption.Due to security reasons in android it demands C A authority signed or trusted certificates

use this plugin to avoid this.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fetch-blob

```
RNFetchBlob.config({
  trusty : true
})
.then('GET', 'https://xxxxx.com')
.then((resp) => {
  // ...
})
```

Add config **trusty** as **true** to trust the certificate when you  POST or GET API's

Comment: As of March 2021 RNFetchBlob gives a variety of issue to get working; 4 hours of debugging without successful result

Comment: You should be aware that the response object of RNFetchBlob is slightly different than that of the fetch method that RN offers. So there is a good chance that you should alter your response parsing logic as well.

Comment: Thx for this answer, I got it to work!
This is how do it:
  RNFetchBlob.config({
    trusty: true
  })
    .fetch('GET', 'https://195.756.2.3:3000')
    .then((response: any) => console.log('response.data:', response.data))
    .catch((error: any) => {
      console.log('fetch failed with this error: ', error);
    });

Answer (score 3):

Piggybacking of @Santiago Jimenez Wilson's answer here.

Obviously patching react-native itself is pretty dirty so we took the suggested override and extracted it into a category.

Just create a new file called `RCTHTTPRequestHandler+yourPatchName.m` somewhere in your project:

```
//
//  RCTHTTPRequestHandler+yourPatchName
//

#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"
#import "RCTHTTPRequestHandler.h"

@implementation RCTHTTPRequestHandler(yourPatchName)

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition, NSURLCredential *credential))completionHandler
{
  completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust]);
}
@end
```

Next step would be to then differ between dev and prod and only overload the method for dev.

Comment: what version of RN are you using?

Comment: That is react-native 0.38

Comment: Did you try to solve this for version 0.40? There is a problem with RCTHTTPRequestHandler.h not beeing visible to user code.

Comment: @leizeQ Use 


    #import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
    #import <React/RCTHTTPRequestHandler.h>

Comment: @EricKim thats not working as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41997905/react-native-0-40-fetch-againts-self-signed-certificate

Comment: @leizeQ It worked for me in 0.41.2 but no longer working in 0.42.0

Answer (score 2):

Just to add information for users looking for Android Solution.
As react-native do not handle SSL Error by default. There is a simple approach to Run your WebView for the websites that must be connected through "https" instead of "http".

I am assuming you have already installed the react-native-webview module using NPM if no then please google.

Once you have "react-native-webview" module inside "node_modules" folder. 
Go inside 
".\node_modules >> react-native-webview >> android >> src >> main >> java >> com >> reactnativecommunity >> webview"

Open "RNCWebViewManager.java" File in Text Editor and Add Below Code

In import section add these two dependencies

```
....
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;
import android.net.http.SslError;
....
```

Now Search for Below "class" inside same file
    **protected static class RNCWebViewClient extends WebViewClient**

And add this method

```
@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView webView, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError 
error) {
    if (error.toString() == "piglet")
        handler.cancel();
    else
        handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
}
```

Next Save the file and Build your Project. It would not show Blank page now and handle the Invalid SSL Error.

Note:

1. Solution works only if you are using "WebView" from "react-native-webview" instead of deprecated "WebView" from "react-native"
2. Make sure you have already linked your "react-native" with "react-native-webview" else it would not be included inside your android project
3. There might be version Error in "RNCWebViewModule", "RNCWebViewManager", "RNCWebViewFileProvider" classes (will be visible once you properly build your project using `react-native run-android` inside AndroidStudio after opening your android project using import) that you can easily fix using AndroidStudio

Answer (score 1):

Second answer is for android, and it is working fine. so use that for android.
for ios actual answer is correct. but its hard to find the RCTNetwork.xcodeproj and also changes will gone if you delete and add the npm modules. so it shard to maintain.

so i have created a javascript for patching.
just executing the below script with node js will patch.
passing the argument -r will remove the patch.

```
 * run this script normally for patching,
 * pass -r argument at the end of the command for removing the patch
 * ex: 
 * patching:         $ node patch_ssl_bypass.js
 * removing patch:   $ node patch_ssl_bypass.js -r
 */

var fs = require('fs');

const isRemove = process.argv[process.argv.length-1] == '-r';

const file =
  'node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/RCTHTTPRequestHandler.mm';
const delemeter = '#pragma mark - NSURLSession delegate';
const code = `
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition, NSURLCredential *credential))completionHandler
{
  completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust]);
}
`;
console.log('#############   Reading File   ###############');
fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function(error, data) {
  if (error) {
    console.log('#############  error reading file  ###############');
    console.error(error);
    return;
  }
  if (data.indexOf(code) < 0 && !isRemove) {
    console.log('#############  Patch is not done.  ###############');
    console.log('#############  Patching file  ###############');
    var parts = data.split(delemeter);
    var newCodeBlock = parts[0] + delemeter + '\n' + code + '\n'+parts[1];
    fs.writeFile(file,newCodeBlock,function(){
        console.log('#############  Successfully patched file  ###############');
        console.log('#############  re build the ios project  ###############');
    })
  }else{
      if (isRemove){
          var updatedCode = data.replace(code,'');
        fs.writeFile(file,updatedCode,function(){
            console.log('#############  Successfully removed patch  ###############');
            console.log('#############  re build the ios project  ###############');
        })
      }else{
        console.log('#############  File already patched. No need again  ###############');
      }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After going through alot of answers this is what working on android
[1]: https://rubyfaby.medium.com/how-to-ignore-ssl-for-react-native-f808810ffaed

**Note:Remove this before going to production.**