# How to configure axios to use SSL certificate?

Tags: node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate, axios

I'm trying to make a request with axios to an api endpoint and I'm getting the following error: `Error: unable to verify the first certificate`

It seems the https module, which axios uses, is unable to verify the SSL certificate used on the server.

When visiting the server with my browser, the certificate is valid and I can see/download it. I can also make requests to the api on my browser through https.

I can work around it by turning off verification. This code works.

```
const result = await axios.post(
    `https://${url}/login`,
    body,
    {
      httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
        rejectUnauthorized: false
      })
    }
  )
```

Problem is, this doesn't verify the SSL certificate and therefore opens up security holes.

How can I configure axios to trust the certificate and correctly verify it?

Comment: use native implementation of OkhttpClientFactory, https://stackoverflow.com/a/60116643/2685454

Comment: In case you are looking for posting using @nestjs/axios, refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/72588991/7102312

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Old question but chiming in for those who land here. No expert. Please consult with your local security gurus and what not.

Axios is an http(s) client and http clients usually participate in TLS anonymously. In other words, the server accepts their connection without identifying who is trying to connect. This is different then say, Mutual TLS where both the server and client verify each other before completing the handshake.

The internet is a scary place and we want to protect our clients from connecting to spoofed public endpoints. We do this by ensuring our clients identify the server before sending any private data.

```
// DO NOT DO THIS IF SHARING PRIVATE DATA WITH SERVICE
const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({ rejectUnauthorized: false });
```

This is often posted (and more egregiously upvoted) as the answer on StackOverflow regarding https client connection failures in any language. And what's worse is that it usually works, unblocks the dev and they move on their merry way. However, while they certainly get in the door, whose door is it? Since they opted out of verifying the server's identity, their poor client has no way of knowing if the connection they just made to the company's intranet has bad actors listening on the line.

If the service has a public SSL cert, the `https.Agent` usually does not need to be configured further because your operating system provides a common set of publicly trusted CA certs. This is usually the same set of CA certs your browser is configured to use and is why a default axios client can hit https://google.com with little fuss.

If the service has a private SSL cert (self signed for testing purposes or one signed by your company's private CA to protect their internal secrets), the https agent must be configured to trust the private CA used to sign the server cert:

```
const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({ ca: MY_CA_BUNDLE });
```

where `MY_CA_BUNDLE` is an array of CA certs with both the server cert for the endpoint you want to hit and that cert's complete cert chain in `.pem` format. You must include all certs in the chain up to the trust root.

---

#### Where are these options documented?

> HTTPS is the HTTP protocol over TLS/SSL. In Node.js this is implemented as a separate module.

Therefore options passed to the `https.Agent` are a merge of the options passed to [`tls.connect()`](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_connect_options_callback) and [`tls.createSecureContext()`](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createsecurecontext_options).

Comment: This finally worked for me after I downloaded the cert and its chain. I had previously failed, because I only downloaded the certificate for the service I wanted to use. For anyone struggling like I was: make sure you download the whole chain as .pem.

Comment: @JemiSalo How to get whole chain of my self signed certificate? I solve id by doing like that: `const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({ ca: fs.readFileSync(certPath) });`

Comment: Where on Earth is this documented? I can't find any reference to a "ca" option in the docs for https.Agent.

Comment: @user1974458 Its super confusing, updated the answer with doc links for options

Comment: I'm really confused here. Why is my browser able to trust a private CA, but axios running from a node script on the same machine is not?!

Comment: @Magnus Both have to be configured to trust the private CA. You don't provide enough information about your environment to understand why your browser trusts the CA and your nodejs client does not. Post in another question and happy to help

Comment: @srquinn Thanks for the offer -- here is the full question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67488917/how-to-get-axios-to-work-with-an-aws-acm-public-certificate

Comment: I was having this issue as well, thanks to this answer and particularly the point where you mention that the whole certificate chain must be available, i was able to finally solve the problem. I had to use a Firefox on Ubuntu to download the PEM chain, it allows you to download either the certificate itself or the full chain, and I used the full chain and fed it in the HTTP agent request and lo and behold, it started to work

Comment: This works fine in node js. what if I wanted to do the same in react native, or in client side.  I already tried to use the native node modules in react native, but it did not work for dependency issues and no good docs about that. I am using expo.

Answer (score 36):

Create a custom agent with SSL certificate:

```
const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
  rejectUnauthorized: false, // (NOTE: this will disable client verification)
  cert: fs.readFileSync("./usercert.pem"),
  key: fs.readFileSync("./key.pem"),
  passphrase: "YYY"
})

axios.get(url, { httpsAgent })

// or

const instance = axios.create({ httpsAgent })
```

From https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/284

Comment: `rejectUnauthorized: false` disables client verification which is one of the OPs primary concerns.

Comment: down voted as it's not wat the OP ask for. This answer, while still correct (except about `rejectUnauthorized`), is about client certificate, where OP want to verify server certificate

Comment: Also I think the key parameter is a bit strange, what is that key of?

Comment: from where we can import https ?? in react native

Comment: is it safe to place this code block on the client side code?

Comment: Do not do this! OP is having problems verifying the server's SSL Cert. You've skipped verification in your 2nd line "rejectUnauthorized: false".

Answer (score 33):

For me, when my application is running in development mode, I have disabled `rejectUnauthorized` directly in `axios.defaults.options`. This works very well. be careful and use this only in developer mode.

```
import https from 'https'
import axios from 'axios'
import config from '~/config'

/**
 * Axios default settings
 */
axios.defaults.baseURL = config.apiURL

/**
 * Disable only in development mode
 */
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  })
  axios.defaults.httpsAgent = httpsAgent
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV, `RejectUnauthorized is disabled.`)
}
```

Comment: Should be noted that this is safe if your server is colocated on `localhost`, but not safe when calling a public endpoint over the interwebs.

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me but had to change `axios.defaults.options` to `axios.defaults.httpsAgent`

Comment: Thanks i have fixed. <o/

Comment: from where you have done import of https? in React Native

Comment: @ShafqatBari the https module is native from nodejs.

Answer (score 12):

These configuration worked for me (In a Mutual Authentication scenario).

```
const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
  ca: fs.readFileSync("./resource/bundle.crt"),        
  cert: fs.readFileSync("./resrouce/thirdparty.crt"),
  key: fs.readFileSync("./resource/key.pem"), 
})
```

Note: bundle.crt was prepared from provided certificates (root,intermediate,end entry certificate). Unfortunately no clear documentation found in this regards.

Comment: to create a bundle just copy the contents of the certificates provided in reverse order into a text file. in `unix` the command would be in your case : `cat thirdparty.crt other.crt > bundle.crt` where the name of the bundle doesn't really matter.

Comment: pleace tell me what is the other.crt? @rawplutonium

Answer (score 10):

This is very dirty, but at the top of your script, just put:

`process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = '0';`

This basically tells node to not check SSL certificates, which is very convenient when you get self signed certificates rejected in development.

Please don't use this in production.

Comment: It doesn't always work.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import https from 'https'

const headers = {};

const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
  ca: fs.readFileSync('./certs/cert.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./certs/cert.pem'),
})

const data = await axios.get(url, { httpsAgent, headers })
```

Comment: from where you have done import of https? in React Native

Comment: its a nodejs core module, won't work in react-native

Comment: How do I get cert.pem file from specific site?

Answer (score 3):

PS : Do not use this in production but just for debugging

This what worked for me, using axios with nodejs + express

```
exports.test_ssl = async (req,res) => { 
       
    let cert_file = fs.readFileSync("./ssl/my_self_signed_certificate.crt")
    let ca_file = fs.readFileSync("./ssl/my_self_signed_certificate_ca.crt")
    const agent = new https.Agent({
        requestCert: true,
        rejectUnauthorized: true, // not for production
        cert: cert_file,
        ca: ca_file
    });
    const options = {
        url: `https://example.com/test`,
        method: "POST",
        httpsAgent: agent,
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/txt;charset=UTF-8'
        },
        data: {}
    };
    
    console.log(cert_file.toString())

    axios(options).then(response => {
        payload = response.data ;
        return res.status(200).send({"status":1});
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        return false
    });

}
```

Comment: This answer has `rejectUnauthorized: false` which turns off the identity check of the server and exposes your client to Man In the Middle attacks. See accepted answer, you should not be doing this in production workloads.

Answer (score 1):

```
const https = require('https');
const axios = require('axios')

const CA = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----$$$$$-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
const url = "bla"
const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
  ca: CA
});

const response = await axios.get(url, { httpsAgent });
```

This is what work for me.

Comment: from where you have done import of https? in React Native

Answer (score -4):

**Install https package**

```
npm i https
```

**create httpsAgent**

```
const https = require('https');
    const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    });
```

**pass this agent in axios call after url**

```
const { data } = await axios.get(url, { httpsAgent });
```

Comment: https://blog.sandworm.dev/security-alert-dont-npm-install-https