# Can Next.js fetch data from an Asp.Net Core API?

Tags: reactjs, api, .net-core, next.js

I am building a Next.js website with an Asp.Net Core API. The API runs on the default port of 5001 (https) and the Next.js server runs on the default port 3000. I'm trying to make a GET request to the API from my Next.js website, however, I receive the following error `Error: unable to verify the first certificate`.
When I manually navigate to the URL of the API in the browser I get the following JSON response

```
[
   {
     "electionId":1,
     "electionType":"General",
     "electionDate":"2020-12-22T11:01:42.6330892",
     "votes":null,
     "candidate_Votes":null
   }
]
```

Which is what I want to display in a table

**What I've done:**

I've setup Next.js to run using https, which didn't resolve the issue.

**server.js**

```
const { createServer } = require('https');
const { parse } = require('url');
const next = require('next');
const fs = require('fs');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

const httpsOptions = {
   key: fs.readFileSync('./localhost.key'),
   cert: fs.readFileSync('./localhost.crt')
};

app.prepare().then(() => {
   createServer(httpsOptions, (req, res) => {
   const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
   handle(req, res, parsedUrl);

}).listen(3000, err => {
   if (err) throw err;
       console.log('> Ready on https://localhost:3000');
   });
});
```

I disabled SSL verification which allowed me to make the request, however this is not the best practice for production.

I was wondering if because the certificates I created for Next.js are different from what was automatically created by the .Net Core API, that I am still getting the verification error. Or because both applications are on different ports.

**How I am making the request:**

```
export async function getStaticProps() {

     const data = await axios.get("https://localhost:5001/api/Elections");

     if (!data) {
        return {
           notFound: true,
        }
     }
     return {
        props: {
           data,
        }
     }
}
```

I also tried using Postman to make the request and received a similar SSL Error. If I disable SSL certification verification then it works as expected.

Comment: Seems related to the SSL certificate, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51363855/how-to-configure-axios-to-use-ssl-certificate

Comment: @juliomalves as you can see in my server.js code, I have already tried most of the suggestions in those answers

Comment: Like the answers suggest, the HTTPS agent must be configured in the `axios` request not in in the custom server.