# Axios: SSL TrustStore Configuration for Certificate with expired Root

Tags: node.js, ssl, axios, ca

I'm fighting with Axios and some destination server which presents a certificate issued by **AddTrust External CA** which expired last year in may. Running `openssl s_client` will print me the following chain:

```
CONNECTED(00000005)
depth=1 C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
verify error:num=10:certificate has expired
notAfter=May 30 10:48:38 2020 GMT
verify return:0
depth=1 C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
verify error:num=10:certificate has expired
notAfter=May 30 10:48:38 2020 GMT
verify return:0
depth=3 C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
verify error:num=10:certificate has expired
notAfter=May 30 10:48:38 2020 GMT
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=<ACTUAL-CERTIFICATE-CN>
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=Sectigo Limited/CN=Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
 1 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=Sectigo Limited/CN=Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
   i:/C=US/ST=New Jersey/L=Jersey City/O=The USERTRUST Network/CN=USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
 2 s:/C=US/ST=New Jersey/L=Jersey City/O=The USERTRUST Network/CN=USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
 3 s:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
[...]
```

I removed the expired CA from my truststore and added

- **Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA** and
- **USERTrust RSA Certification Authority**

but I'm still ending up with `UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY`.

Other connections to trusted destinations are working fine with mTLS.

As I don't want to end up using `rejectUnauthorized = false`, is there any way to make this work properly?

My SSL configuration was done like this:

```
https.globalAgent.options.ca = fs.readFileSync('ca.crt')
https.globalAgent.options.cert = fs.readFileSync('public.crt')
https.globalAgent.options.key = fs.readFileSync('private.pem')
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you ever tried this by referring to this article?[how-to-configure-axios-ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51363855/how-to-configure-axios-to-use-ssl-certificate)

Comment: Yes that's what I have done :-) my other connections are working, I think the issue here is the expired CA.