# FetchError: unable to verify the first certificate, but I added rejectUnauthorized: false

Tags: javascript, https, axios, next.js

I have a simple `getServerSideProps()` function that calls an external API but throws this error:

> FetchError: request to https://nginx/api/items failed, reason: unable
> to verify the first certificate

The Node server does not trust my self-signed certificate.

So I found this Stack Overflow post to bypass that (I'm only using it in development):

[How to configure axios to use SSL certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51363855/how-to-configure-axios-to-use-ssl-certificate)

So I added the `rejectUnauthorized: false` to my Axios call like so:

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
const res = await fetch('https://nginx/api/items',
   { rejectUnauthorized: false,
     method: 'GET',
   }
)

const { data } = await res.json()
return { props: { data } }
}
```

But I still get the error.

Is there another way to make my self-signed certificate work with Next? I found some other solutions, but they are for Express, I don't know how to implement that for Node with Next.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `rejectUnautorized` belongs in an `HttpAgent`:

```js
const https = require('https');
const agent = new https.Agent({
  rejectUnauthorized: false
});
const res = await fetch('https://nginx/api/items', { 
     method: 'GET',
     agent
   }
);
```

Comment: Thank you!!! Wow. Just needed to add `const https = require('https');`