# Does Axios perform SSL verification by default in a React Native/NodeJS environment?

Tags: node.js, react-native, axios, postman, ssl-certificate

I noticed that while having SSL verification enabled in Postman, endpoints served under certificates issued by *R3* fail with the error "SSL verification failed", whereas in a React Native environment if the same call was made using `axios` the call went through successfully.

Some more digging and landed at the `http.Agent` and `https.Agent` options in `axios`:

[https.Agent options image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCUCB.png)

The default options do not seem to be *disabling* anything related to SSL verification. But [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51363855/how-to-configure-axios-to-use-ssl-certificate) issue (along with many others) suggest having a problem with SSL verification and having to set `rejectUnauthorized` param as `false` while creating a custom `https.Agent` so that their API calls go through.

From the [https.request docs](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#httpsrequesturl-options-callback) for `nodejs`, under the examples we can see most of them are pinning certs and there is no option or param to enable a generic SSL verification (like in Postman for example).

In summary,

1. Is SSL verification disabled by default in `axios` even when using an HTTPS endpoint? Or is this only applicable in browser environments and driven by the browser's inherent CA verification process?
2. Do we need to perform certificate pinning to get any kind of SSL verification in a React Native environment?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Axios does SSL verification by default, but `Agent` overwrites this. However, in most environments I would not disable it. R3 should not be rejected by postman, sounds like maybe you're using a certificate store that for some reason doesn't include R3.