# Nextjs using SSL proxy still meets UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE when requesting https API

Tags: ssl, https, next.js

I want to know

1. Why this happens
2. How to solve it *gracefully*

Here's my situation.

- My local **non-custom** nextjs needs to serve over https in domain `my.company.com`. (cookies are concerned)
- This script solves **incoming** https request (from [this solution](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/10935#discussioncomment-1540436)): `local-ssl-proxy --key ./certs/key.pem --cert ./certs/cert.pem --source 3000 --target 3001) & next dev -p 3001`
  (the key and the cert are for `*.company.com` from public CA)
- But server to server **outgoing** https requests through an axios instance still meets `UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE`, **why?**
- Adding node option `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` to the above script (or [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64128763/10694438)) solves local dev environment, but this doesn't really look safe. Would there be an actual solution **while not using a web server and not using custom nextjs server**? I don't want neither my local dev environment to be heavy or to break nextjs routing feature.