# React with Axios gives net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: reactjs

On my local development machine I have created a backend in Python and a frontend in React.

**Backend**

I use Flask API in Python to generate the backend, and for the certificate I have generated a self created one using the following command in Ubuntu:

`openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -out cert.pem -keyout key.pem -days 365`

This genrates a self signed certificate.

When I got to my API at https://localhost:5000/api/customers/get_customers I get a list of customers (the data is development data):

```
[
  {
    "customer_created_timestamp": "Fri, 07 Oct 2022 14:16:36 GMT",
    "customer_id": 22,
    "customer_name": "Juno",
    "customer_name_abbreviated": "JUN"
  },
  {
    "customer_created_timestamp": "Fri, 07 Oct 2022 14:16:36 GMT",
    "customer_id": 23,
    "customer_name": "Minnie",
    "customer_name_abbreviated": "MIN"
  },
  {
    "customer_created_timestamp": "Fri, 07 Oct 2022 14:16:36 GMT",
    "customer_id": 26,
    "customer_name": "Aspen",
    "customer_name_abbreviated": "ASP"
  },
  {
    "customer_created_timestamp": "Fri, 07 Oct 2022 14:16:36 GMT",
    "customer_id": 29,
    "customer_name": "Charlie",
    "customer_name_abbreviated": "CHA"
  },
  {
    "customer_created_timestamp": "Fri, 07 Oct 2022 14:16:36 GMT",
    "customer_id": 30,
    "customer_name": "Katie",
    "customer_name_abbreviated": "KAT"
  },
  {
    "customer_created_timestamp": "Fri, 07 Oct 2022 14:16:36 GMT",
    "customer_id": 31,
    "customer_name": "Dolly",
    "customer_name_abbreviated": "DOL"
  },
  {
    "customer_created_timestamp": "Fri, 07 Oct 2022 14:16:36 GMT",
    "customer_id": 32,
    "customer_name": "Nova",
    "customer_name_abbreviated": "NOV"
  },
  {
    "customer_created_timestamp": "Fri, 07 Oct 2022 14:16:36 GMT",
    "customer_id": 33,
    "customer_name": "Piper",
    "customer_name_abbreviated": "PIP"
  },
  {
    "customer_created_timestamp": "Fri, 07 Oct 2022 14:16:36 GMT",
    "customer_id": 37,
    "customer_name": "Belle",
    "customer_name_abbreviated": "BEL"
  },
  {
    "customer_created_timestamp": "Fri, 07 Oct 2022 14:16:36 GMT",
    "customer_id": 38,
    "customer_name": "Harper",
    "customer_name_abbreviated": "HAR"
  },
  {
    "customer_created_timestamp": "Fri, 07 Oct 2022 14:16:36 GMT",
    "customer_id": 40,
    "customer_name": "Daisy",
    "customer_name_abbreviated": "DAI"
  },
  {
    "customer_created_timestamp": "Fri, 07 Oct 2022 14:20:56 GMT",
    "customer_id": 41,
    "customer_name": "Ava",
    "customer_name_abbreviated": "AVA"
  },
  {
    "customer_created_timestamp": "Fri, 07 Oct 2022 14:20:56 GMT",
    "customer_id": 42,
    "customer_name": "Lacey",
    "customer_name_abbreviated": "LAC"
  },
  {
    "customer_created_timestamp": "Fri, 07 Oct 2022 14:20:56 GMT",
    "customer_id": 43,
    "customer_name": "Millie",
    "customer_name_abbreviated": "MIL"
  },
  {
    "customer_created_timestamp": "Fri, 07 Oct 2022 14:20:56 GMT",
    "customer_id": 44,
    "customer_name": "Trixie",
    "customer_name_abbreviated": "TRI"
  },
  {
    "customer_created_timestamp": "Fri, 07 Oct 2022 14:20:56 GMT",
    "customer_id": 45,
    "customer_name": "Zoey",
    "customer_name_abbreviated": "ZOE"
  },
  {
    "customer_created_timestamp": "Fri, 07 Oct 2022 14:20:56 GMT",
    "customer_id": 46,
    "customer_name": "Luna",
    "customer_name_abbreviated": "LUN"
  },
  {
    "customer_created_timestamp": "Fri, 07 Oct 2022 14:20:56 GMT",
    "customer_id": 47,
    "customer_name": "Lola",
    "customer_name_abbreviated": "LOL"
  },
  {
    "customer_created_timestamp": "Fri, 07 Oct 2022 14:20:56 GMT",
    "customer_id": 48,
    "customer_name": "Olive",
    "customer_name_abbreviated": "OLI"
  }
]
```

**Frontend**

Now In my frontend I want to use React to get the customers and print them in a table. However I get the error "net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID". I guess its because of the certificate.

This is my **Customers.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Customers extends React.Component {
  state = {
    customers: []
  }

  
  componentDidMount() {

    let config = {
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json', 
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      }
    }
    
    let data = {
      'HTTP_CONTENT_LANGUAGE': 'no',
    }

    axios.get('https://localhost:5000/api/customers/get_customers', data, config)
      .then(res => {
        const customers = res.data;
        this.setState({ customers });
      })
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <table className="hor-zebra">
       <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <span><a href="#">ID</a></span>
          </th>
          <th>
            <span><a href="#">Name</a></span>
          </th>
          <th>
            <span><a href="#">Abbreviated</a></span>
          </th>
          <th>
            <span><a href="#">Created</a></span>
          </th>
         </tr>
        </thead>
       <tbody>
        {
          this.state.customers
          .map((customer, index) => {


            return ( 
              <tr key={index}>
              <td><span>{index}</span></td>
                <td><span>{customer.customer_name}</span></td>
                <td><span>{customer.customer_name_abbreviated}</span></td>
                <td><span>{customer.customer_created_timestamp}</span></td>
              </tr>
            );
           }
          )
        }
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  };
};
```

This is my **App.js**

```
import './App.css';

import React from 'react';
import Customers from './components/Customers.js';


function App() {
  


  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="container">
        <header>
          <p>Customers</p>
        </header>

        <main>
          <Customers />
        </main>
      </div>
    </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

**What I need help with**

I need either a mode of creating a certificate (that is free) or I need to somehow make React accept the certificate.

I read on [How to configure axios to use SSL certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51363855/how-to-configure-axios-to-use-ssl-certificate) that you could add

`const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({ ca: MY_CA_BUNDLE });`

However where do I add this? Is this correct? I have in my backend files named "key.pem" and "cert.pem".