# Cannot make axios post request in Node.js to an API endpoint not owned by me

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, cookies, axios

there is the website https://cebcare.ceb.lk/Incognito/DemandMgmtSchedule and in there I can see an API call to https://cebcare.ceb.lk/Incognito/GetLoadSheddingEvents with `StartTime` and `EndTime` as form data.

I tried to send post request to above endpoint in Node.js using axios but I get the error `AxiosError: unable to verify the first certificate` and `code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE'`

Then I saw that there are 2 Headers `RequestVerificationToken` and `Cookie`. I grabbed them and did a Postman request and got back a response with 200. But in Node.js when I do like

```
const data = {
  StartTime: startDate,
  EndTime: endDate,
};

const response = await axios.post(URL, data, {
  "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
  Cookie:
    ".AspNetCore.Antiforgery.ThOcTlhnrMo=CfDJ8Nr2EC612OFAjHvozOYXtlRQE9n05fuSOD0jEvKY0unmx8QyMYxdCfmotrhzVIKzurnhpkY_MtfAP9cmpR11u8rzt7_xz4IkuWMURwfelg7ymSJ8GaksLVwEgbMIkEDfrvjb5II6EzzTaLA5RiXRDXU",
  RequestVerificationToken:
    "CfDJ8Nr2EC612OFAjHvozOYXtlRBtAUjb36TUpOhI0yuLADjcckB_h1xKJWHDwl0MrqyE4_4pU_YXUkeh5uI66UBXedMcMmihENJ5hpfW_vBgNWZJ-JtliiE4UYvxNJCvvhmGvIWSKWeeqx-llCxrPio9Tw",
});
```

I get the same error as above

Is there a way to fix this. Or somehow bypass the `Cookie` and `RequestVerificationToken`. Or can I hardcode these 2 values and send request?

**EDIT**
I did the following after looking at the linked post

```
const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({ rejectUnauthorized: false });

const response = await axios.post(URL, data, {
  httpsAgent,
  "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
  Cookie:
    ".AspNetCore.Antiforgery.ThOcTlhnrMo=CfDJ8Nr2EC612OFAjHvozOYXtlRQE9n05fuSOD0jEvKY0unmx8QyMYxdCfmotrhzVIKzurnhpkY_MtfAP9cmpR11u8rzt7_xz4IkuWMURwfelg7ymSJ8GaksLVwEgbMIkEDfrvjb5II6EzzTaLA5RiXRDXU",
  RequestVerificationToken:
    "CfDJ8Nr2EC612OFAjHvozOYXtlRBtAUjb36TUpOhI0yuLADjcckB_h1xKJWHDwl0MrqyE4_4pU_YXUkeh5uI66UBXedMcMmihENJ5hpfW_vBgNWZJ-JtliiE4UYvxNJCvvhmGvIWSKWeeqx-llCxrPio9Tw",
});
```

but now I'm getting Bad Request 400. But in postman Im getting the results for the same `Cookie` and `RequestVerificationToken`

Comment: Please research before posting in accordance with [ask]; this is a duplicate of [How to configure axios to use SSL certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51363855/how-to-configure-axios-to-use-ssl-certificate)

Comment: @esqew thank you for directing me. but I can't seem to figure out what's going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third parameter of the axios post function takes an "Options" object - as for your case to pass the headers you should write like this:

```
{ 
   headers: {
     'Content-Type:'multipart/form-data',
     Cookie: "",
     RequestVerificationToken: ""
   } 
}
```

Comment: oh cool. now I get the results thank you!

Comment: btw do you think I can use the Cookie and RequestVerificationToken forever if I am creating an API for myself using the data fetched from above call.

Comment: i'm sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: hi what I meant was for me to get the data I need to send in the value for Cookie and RequestVerificationToken. I got those values copied from the network tab in https://cebcare.ceb.lk/Incognito/DemandMgmtSchedule. Can I hardcode those 2 values in my express server or do they change in a way that I cannot call the API anymore