# Axios call with Azure AD authorization to my API does not work (error 401)

Tags: node.js, asp.net-web-api, axios, azure-active-directory

EDIT 1: I initially thought the calls were working when the application was deployed on the server but it is not the case.

**Context:**

- Single Page Application (SPA) in Vue.js (vue3 composition API)
- Use of MSAL library for Azure AD authentication (@azure/msal-browser@^2.32.2)
- ASP.Net Core Web API (.Net 7)
- Axios for API call from the SPA (axios@1.2.4)

  - a request interceptor uses MSAL to retrieve an access token (JWT Bearer) which is sent as an authorization header with the request.

**The problem:**

Calls from the SPA to the API return a 401 error.

Other calls are working:

- local calls from Swagger UI
- local curl command with --insecure option
- local calls from [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest) with certificate validation disabled
- <del>server calls from the SPA to the API are working (both deployed on our server)</del>
  EDIT 1: It doesn't.
- local calls from the SPA to operations of the API that do not require authorization

**Environment:**

- Windows 10 development PC
- The SPA runs locally with [Vite](https://vitejs.dev)

  - Running the build version with `vite preview` has the same problem.
- I use Edge (chromium) for my tests. The same problem occurs with Firefox or other chromium browsers.
- The API runs locally on IIS Express (https with certificate generated by IIS Express)

---

<del>Since the solution is working on the server, I suppose the Azure AD configuration is correct.</del>
EDIT 1: There may be a mistake in the AAD configuration.

And since I can make local calls to the local API from other sources, I suppose the API configuration is also correct.

My best guess is that there is a problem in the axios call but only locally and only when there is authorization involved.

## Azure AD setup

I followed the following tutorials to setup Azure AD

**[Azure AD tutorial for Javascript Single Page App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-auth-code)**
It uses MSAL to interact with Azure AD. I also added an axios request interceptor to retrieve the access token automatically for each request.

**[Azure AD tutorial for ASP.NET API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/web-api-tutorial-01-register-app)**
The authorization configuration sets up a policy with a scope requirement. The policy is called "AuthZPolicy" and I called my scope "access_as_user".

The controllers are decorated with the attribute `[Authorize(Policy = "AuthZPolicy")]`

I understand the authentication/authorization flow is the following:

1. The user authenticates with their company credentials
2. MSAL gets an IdToken and stores it in the local storage
3. When a page makes a request, the interceptor uses MSAL to fetch an access token. The access token contains the claim `"scp": "access_as_user"`.
4. The access token is sent in the authorization header of the request to the API.
5. At this point, I expect the API to validate the token and return a response. However a *401* error is returned.

## What I tried

### Disable authorization

I tried disabling the authorization in the API by removing the *Authorize* attribute on the controller.

I can also disable it by not specifying any scopes in the authorization configuration

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(config =>
{
    config.AddPolicy("AuthZPolicy", policyBuilder =>
        policyBuilder.Requirements.Add(new ScopeAuthorizationRequirement(/* no scopes required */)));
}
```

In both cases, the calls return the expected data, but this is not acceptable as we need authorization.

### Use https for the SPA

I was launching the SPA in http. Lauching it in https (using [@vitejs/plugin-basic-ssl](https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-basic-ssl)) did not change the behaviour.

### Disable *rejectUnauthorized* in axios

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51363855/how-to-configure-axios-to-use-ssl-certificate).

I was hoping setting *rejectUnauthorized* to *false* would have the same effect as the *--insecure* option in curl or disabling certificate validation in Insomnia.

I can't make it work because "https" cannot be used in a browser context. I get the following error

> Module "https" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "https.Agent" in client code.  See http://vitejs.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#module-externalized-for-browser-compatibility for more details.

I did not try setting up a custom certificate as discussed in the question mentioned above as I don't know how to do it. I assume I would have to configure a certificate for IIS Express and then get the certificate chain to configure Axios.

## Call details

### Call from the SPA (not working)

In the developer tools I see the following

**General Headers**

```
Request URL: https://localhost:44342/api/Reason/GetAll
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 401 
Remote Address: [::1]:44342
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

**Response Headers**

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: https://localhost:44340
access-control-expose-headers: Content-Disposition
date: Fri, 02 Jun 2023 14:07:59 GMT
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
vary: Origin
www-authenticate: Bearer
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
```

**Request Headers**

```
:authority: localhost:44342
:method: GET
:path: /api/Reason/GetAll
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6
authorisation: Bearer t0K3n
origin: https://localhost:44340
referer: https://localhost:44340/
sec-ch-ua: "Microsoft Edge";v="113", "Chromium";v="113", "Not-A.Brand";v="24"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/113.0.1774.57
```

**API logs**
In the console of the API, I see the following messages

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2 OPTIONS https://localhost:44342/api/Reason/GetAll - -
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[4]
      CORS policy execution successful.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished HTTP/2 OPTIONS https://localhost:44342/api/Reason/GetAll - - - 204 - - 0.4755ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:44342/api/Reason/GetAll - -
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[4]
      CORS policy execution successful.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
      ScopeAuthorizationRequirement:Scope=
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[12]
      AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:44342/api/Reason/GetAll - - - 401 - - 0.5798ms
```

Even though the scope is present in the access token, we see the follwing message :

> Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
> ScopeAuthorizationRequirement:Scope=

### Call from Swagger UI (working)

Swagger UI opens when I launch the API.
If I authenticate in Swagger UI with the token, I get a *code 200* response with the expected results. The token is copy-pasted from the authorization header in the request from the dev tools.

### Call with curl (working with --insecure option)

Swagger UI generates a curl command. It looks like this:

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://localhost:44342/api/Reason/GetAll' \
  -H 'accept: text/plain' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer t0K3n'
```

When execute it in a git bash terminal, I get the following error message:

> curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
> More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html
>
> curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
> establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
> how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.

I understand this is because the API is running on IIS Express with a self signed certificate.

When I use the `--insecure` option I get the expected results.

### Call with Insomnia (working without certificate validation)

Insomina is a tool to test rest API's: https://insomnia.rest

Similarly to curl, I get an error when Insomnia tries to validate the certificate of the server but I get the expected response when I disable certificate validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a typo in the name of the Authorization header, I had spelled it "Authorisation" (with s instead of z)