# Why the CA root certificate cannot work in some environment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables

This is my package.json fragment:

```
 "scripts": {
    "work":"cross-env NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=\".\\CA.cer\" nodemon ./index.js",
    "start": "nodemon -r dotenv/config ./index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

the .env file content:

```
 NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=.\CA.cer
```

the index.js fragment:

```
import axios from "axios";
import 'dotenv/config';
const api = axios.create();
// add the response interceptor
api.interceptors.response.use(
    null, // default success handler
    (error) => {
        return Promise.reject({
            status: error.response?.status,
            message:
                error.response?.data ?? error.response?.statusText ?? error.message,
        });
    },
    {
        synchronous: true, // optimise interceptor handling
    }
);
const fetch = async (data, method, url, responseType, headers) => {
    const requestObj = {
        url,
        method,
        responseType,
        headers,
        [method.toLowerCase() === "get" ? "params" : "data"]: data,
    };
    //console.log(requestObj);
    const response = await api(requestObj); // use the created instance
    if (response.request.responseType === "blob") {
        let fileName = response.headers["content-disposition"];
        fileName = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("filename=") + 9);
        const newBlob = new Blob([response.data], {
            type: response.headers.get("content-type"),
        });
        const objUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = objUrl;
        link.download = fileName;
        link.click();
    }
    return response.data;
};
.........

console.log(process.env.NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS);

try {
    //console.log(url);
    let result = await fetch(null, "get", url,null , header);
    //console.log(result);
} catch (error) {
    console.log("An Error occur:");
    console.log(error.message);
    console.log("==========================================");
}
```

When I execute the following command:

```
npm run work
```

It returns the following:

```
.\CA.cer
```

However, when I execute the following command:

```
npm run start
```

It returns the following :

```
.\CA.cer
An Error occur:
unable to verify the first certificate
```

In both cases the environmental variables `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` can be accessed, why the second case prompt the error?

Would you tell me what happening?

Finally, I follow [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51363855/how-to-configure-axios-to-use-ssl-certificate) to solve the problem.

```
const fetch = async (data, method, url, responseType, headers, httpsAgent) => {
    const requestObj = {
        headers,
        httpsAgent,
        method,
        responseType,
        url,
        [method.toLowerCase() === "get" ? "params" : "data"]: data,
    };
    //console.log(requestObj);
    const response = await api(requestObj); // use the created instance
    if (response.request.responseType === "blob") {
        let fileName = response.headers["content-disposition"];
        fileName = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("filename=") + 9);
        const newBlob = new Blob([response.data], {
            type: response.headers.get("content-type"),
        });
        const objUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = objUrl;
        link.download = fileName;
        link.click();
    }
    return response.data;
};


//console.log(process.env.NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS)
const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
    ca: fs.readFileSync(process.env.NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS),
});
try {
    //console.log(url);
    let result = await fetch(null, "get", url, null, header, httpsAgent);
    console.log(result.count);
} catch (error) {
    console.log("An Error occur:");
    console.log(error.message);
    console.log("==========================================");
}
```

Comment: `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` is an environment variable that must be passed to the `node` executable itself, not just be available to js code in `process.env`.

Comment: See also https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/20432