How to configure axios to use SSL certificate with an umbrella proxy pac?
We're trying to use axios to contact some APÏ using a proxy pac umbrella.
We're using the conf we've seen around here but have the same error as this topic :
How to configure axios to use SSL certificate?
But we could not solve it, even with the whole umbrella chain down to their CA.
My interlocutor is not familiar with Axios at all, and block on the " why could you not use the windows machine certificate store"
My question would be, what exactly is expected from Axios to work ? What can we try more ? Even to have a more precise information.
Thanks.
We tried all of this :
How to configure axios to use SSL certificate?
We made it working by deactivating ssl verification. But that's no valid fix long term wise.

"We tried all of this : ..." - the answer given there (use the ca argument) is correct. Likely you've applied it wrong then to your specific situation. Unfortunately you don't show what you exactly did.

I cant show much cos it's not mine. But lets just say its an angular front making api calls. It works. But they asked to go through their proxy and I assumed the ca way from the topic was it. But seems not. What is axios expecting really ?

I'm assuming that with "proxy pac umbrella" you mean that your browser has configured a pac file which makes you to use a proxy provided by a Cisco umbrella product and this proxy does SSL interception and you want to properly validate the (intercepted) server certificate. In this case the ca argument should be the CA of the proxy, which is issuing the server certificates during SSL interception. Still no idea what you really did, i.e. if you did the wrong arguments or the wrong certificates or both.

That's exactly it.
Since this is in a client context I can't show much.
We tried with the full chain from proxy downloaded from browser but to no result.
We're doing this :
const httpsAgent = new HttpsProxyAgent({
host: IDNCONFIG.proxy_httpshost,
port: IDNCONFIG.proxy_httpsport,
rejectUnauthorized: false,
ca: CA
});
where CA is "fs.readFileSync(IDNCONFIG.umbrellaRootCAPath);"
We log the process and it is reading the CA so I guess the CA must be wrong ?

"so I guess the CA must be wrong" - that's the only explanation I have so far

As of today we're getting the " unable to get issuer certificate locally" from Axios.
I can't wrap my head around it.
We tried with the umbrella CA, which is signed by umbrella itself, since the client said they usually do like this .
But, let's say were trying to call https://api.com
going from browser to that site would should that certificate chain
Client-CA
umbrella CA
umbrella intermediate CA
umbrella daily generated CA
api.com CA.
I'm no expert on that question, So I don't know what is really required.

We tried to add clientCA, umbrellaCA and umbrellaIntermediateCA, still "unable to get issuer certificate locally" error.
We will try with the whole chain, but I've doubt it'd work.
It's lack of knowledge from my part, but I'm not finding anything making me understand this more easily.

If How to configure axios to use SSL certificate? (whose first answer is about server certificates) did not help you, you are probably talking about a client certificate.
You include this in your axios request configuration as
httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
  cert: fs.readFileSync("<path to your cert.pem file>"),
  key: fs.readFileSync("<path to your key.pem file>"),
  passphrase: "<passphrase protecting your private key>"
})

Instead of cert and key, you can include one property
  cert: fs.readFileSync("<path to your pfx file>"),

if you store your certificate in PFX (PKCS#12) format.
(This is essentially the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/52065387/16462950.)

This is about configuring a client certificate. This problem the OP seems to habe is instead about the CA certificate used by some SSL interception solution - "proxy pac umbrella" likely meaning to having a proxy pac file which is configured to use a Cisco umbrella proxy which does SSL interception (really, that should have been way more descriptive by the OP).
