# React Native fetch https localhost network request failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch, expo

I'm trying to fetch a locally hosted API from ASP.NET server:

```
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`https://localhost:2318/api/Restaurant`)
    const data = await response.json()
    console.log(data)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
```

However, it throws an error:

```
Network request failed
at node_modules/whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd.js:535:17 in setTimeout$argument_0
```

None of my endpoints work. Fetching from public APIs works. Also strange that opening the fetching url https://localhost:2318/api/Restaurant in Safari inside the simulator works and returns the data as expected.

I'm using Expo v42.0.1, RN v0.66.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure it is https?

Comment: @KenyiLarcher I'm pretty sure yes, because entering url with https works in simulator's safari, while entering url with http says "Safari cannot open the page because the network connection was lost."

Answer (score 1):

You are making a request to the localhost server which is going to have a self-signed certificate. So either iOS or Android won't allow fetching from that API straightaway.

The easiest solution would be using [react-native-fetch-blob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fetch-blob#self-signed-ssl-server). (Just pass trusty as true).

```
RNFetchBlob.config({
  trusty : true
})
.then('GET', 'https://example.com')
.then((resp) => {
  // ...
})
```

**And if you still want to use *fetch* and try the below solution.**

1. If you are using the iOS device to test :
   You can do two things:

- *Either you can make an HTTP call (change https to http in your url) using the below implementation.*

> If you want to enable HTTP requests add this to your info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

- *You can use HTTPS (self-signed) calls using the below implementation.*

  [React-native fetch() from https server with self-signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36289125/react-native-fetch-from-https-server-with-self-signed-certificate)

2. If you are using an Android device to test :

   Try the below solution :
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/55246927/8893384

Comment: react-native-fetch-blob doesn't work with Expo as I understand. I ended up changing our local server's URL to HTTP only, fetching from which works perfectly fine in React Native. I think in the future we'll have to think about signing a normal certificate.