# React Native network failed on fetch when calling https

Tags: react-native, fetch-api

When calling an API running on another computer within the same network (`fetch('https://192...` ), with generated SSL certificate (not trusted) the call always fails with `TypeError: Network call failed`

I have tried `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` in Info.plist and it still doesn't work.

`"react-native": "0.66.4"`

Could not find a solution to make this work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-native fetch() from https server with self-signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36289125/react-native-fetch-from-https-server-with-self-signed-certificate)

Comment: Thanks, haven't tried that. I will leave the question maybe somebody knows a less hackish solution.

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work for me.