# React Native : "TypeError: Network Request Failed" from request to HTTPS Localhost (iOS MacOS)

Tags: ios, reactjs, typescript, react-native, fetch

I have an issue with React Native 0.71 when I make an HTTP Request to an API hosted on Localhost on the port 8000. This API works with Symfony 6.2 and uses the HTTPS protocol.

This issue occurs on the iOS Simulator and I launch the application with Metro on my MacOS.

When I fetch the mockup API provided by ReactNative (`https://reactnative.dev/movies.json`) [as explained in the official documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/network#handling-the-response), everything works fine. But when I make a request to my API hosted on localhost, I have the following error : `TypeError: Network Request Failed`.
The errors occurs also if I use an external package like `Axios`.

This error occurs with this following address : `https://localhost:8000/api/foo` but also if I use the localhost IP address : `https://127.0.0.1/api/foo`.

Here is my code :

```js
// Works perfectly (snippet from the official React Native documentation) 
const getMoviesFromApi = () => {
  return fetch('https://reactnative.dev/movies.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      console.log(json.movies);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
};

// Didn't work
const getMoviesFromApiLocalhost = () => {
  return fetch('https://localhost:8000/api/foo')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      console.log(json.movies);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
};

// Didn't work
const getMoviesFromApiLocalhostIpAddress = () => {
  return fetch('https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/foo')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      console.log(json.movies);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
};
```

If anyone has an idea, that would be great 
Thanks in advance for your help ❤️

Comment: Try using http instead of https . Or check if your endpoint is giving some output on browser ( to check if server is up or not )

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Of course I have verified that my API works with my browser and Postman. I want to find a better solution than just disabling HTTPS. I found a solution with the `info` file in the iOS folder to disable the HTTPS requirement but in the end, when I publish my app and API on the web, it will use HTTPS protocol so I want to use this protocol locally.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-native fetch() from https server with self-signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36289125/react-native-fetch-from-https-server-with-self-signed-certificate)

Comment: Yup, but that solution doesn't work either  but thanks for your answer

Comment: @Alexandre Localhost uses http instead of https. That's why I told you to use it. Can you please give it a shot ?

Comment: @Suyash Vashishtha it's work with HTTP instead of HTTPS, but in development I use the HTTPS protocol, so I want to continu to use this protocol and make API call to my local API with HTTPS. For the moment, as I haven't found an answer, I'm running my API with HTTP, but I'd still like to be able to run it with HTTPS.

Comment: @Suyash Vashishtha i'm the developer of the API so when I launch my local development server, I choose if I want to run it with HTTP or HTTPS.

Comment: As of my knowledge, we develop the APIs in localhost on HTTP and they generally work pretty well in actual deployment with HTTPS.